# Escape the content inside a <script> tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt, escaping, script-tag

I want to store XSLT code in a HTML file like that:

```
<script id="xsltCode" type="text/xml">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    ...
      <script>...</script>
    ...
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</script>
```

As you can see, the problem I have is caused by the `<script>` tag inside the XSLT code. What is the simplest solution to escape it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That looks like a bad idea. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I'm trying to store a XSLT code that will later be used to transform a XML file provided by the user. I don't want to retrieve this code with a XMLHttpRequest because I want all my application condensed in 1 file. The XSLT code never changes.

Comment: How exactly did you determine that there is a problem?

Comment: Because as Senrab said, the `</script>` tag inside the XSLT code is treated as the closing tag of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing arbitrary tags in there isn't really advisable. If you can't load the XSLT separately, alternatives are:

- Store it in a JavaScript string (cleanest option)
- Properly escape the XSLT:

  - `<` needs to be escaped with `&lt;`
  - Any XML entity escapes already existing in your XSLT need to be double-escaped. E.g. if there is an `&amp;` or a numeric escape like `&#10;`, turn those into `&amp;amp;` and `&amp;#10;`.
- Use XHTML where mixing in other XML is not a problem. (However, you have to serve it with the correct mimetype and make sure you work cleanly. This is a clean but "old-fashioned" solution.)

In any case, leave out the XML declaration. It doesn't make sense here and could even cause problems.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason reason why "*throwing arbitrary tags in there isn't really advisable*"?  From what I am reading about the `script` tag, it should be perfectly able to contain any XML document (although I suspect the MIME type needs to be `application/xml` and the XML declaration should be removed).

Comment: I'm not aware of that the `<script>` element should support `application/xml`. Do you have a link to anything that describes this?  I can't find anything [in the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element). Even if the `application/xml` trick is supposed to work in theory, I don't think it works in practice ([see example](http://jsbin.com/josoqeqapo/edit?html,output)).

Comment: 1. As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_and_MIME), both `application/xml` and `text/xml` should work fine. 2. I see nothing wrong with your "in practice" example, despite the misspelling of the MIME type.

Comment: What do you mean the XML declaration? The `<?xml ...?>` line?

Comment: @michael.hor257k The question is whether the mimtypes are officially supported by the `<script>` element – after all the browser would have to switch to the XML parser, so support is not "automatic". You got me with the misspelled MIME type, but [it makes not difference if I correct it](http://jsbin.com/kuyemidife/edit?html,output). In both cases, the text `foo` should not be rendered because it's part of the (outer) `<script>` element.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#XML_declaration)

Comment: I see what you mean. I tend to think it's a bug, but since both Firefox and Safari render the same, I won't argue the point.

Comment: Why do I have to leave out the XML declaration?

Comment: @JacopoStanchi An XML declaration only makes sense for standalone XML files and must be the first thing in the file. It tells the consumer which encoding is used. In HTML, `<meta charset>` is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

`{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}` might work as a replacement for your first `</script>` tag. I believe your issue is that the first `</script>` is treated as the closing tag of your `<script id="xsltCode" type="text/xml">`, which obviously breaks your code. Result:

```html
<script id="xsltCode" type="text/xml">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    ...
      <script>...{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
    ...
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</script>
```